# Como obtener un dato de un formulario general C# a una clase para hacer una consulta SQL?

Tags: c#

Tengo un programa en c#. En la primera ventana, ya cuento con algunos datos, de acuerdo a los datos de acceso, se genera un prefijo en un label.Agregue un botón, que me abrirá una ventana nueva con un datagrid.La información del datagrid la obtengo de una clase que cree en un principio.
Mi consulta es, ¿Comó agrego el texto del label de la primera ventana, a la clase, para poder agregar ese texto a mi consulta SQL?

```
namespace generateQR.Utils
{ 
    public class viajes
    {
        Conexion cn = new Conexion();

        public DataTable MostrarViajes()
        {

            SqlDataAdapter datos = new SqlDataAdapter("select Substring(folio,5,11) as #DeViaje,CONVERT(varchar, fecha, 101) as fecha,proveedor from  TBL_Recolectores_historial where (enviado_SAP='0') and fecha >=CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 101);", cn.Leercadena());
//(en mi consulta sql, agregaria al final un "...and cacopio="+informaciondellabel+";"
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        datos.Fill(dt);
            return(dt);
        }
```

Comment: Pasando por parámetro un string en tu método de `MostrarViajes()` obtienes el valor que deseas

Comment: o cargando una propiedad de la clase... o pasandole el form (no deberias pero bue) y leyendo el label (si este es publico).. formas hay muchas, intentaste algo?

Comment: he intentado varios metodos, desde abstraer simplemente el dato a mi nuevo form "destino", y de ahi tratar volver a abstraerlo a la clase sin éxito. el label lo tengo público, pero no logró abstraer su .Text para utilizarlo en mi consulta. Como se observa, en el nuevo form realizó una consulta para mostrar en el datagrid, pero debo agregar una condición más que de acuerdo a ese label.

Comment: Si quieres enviar un valor de una pantalla a otra puedes hacerlo sobrecargando el constructor y a tu segundo constructor le agregas el tipo de variable que quieras o un objeto, entonces se lo pasas y trabajas lo que necesites en el segundo constructor. No te olvides de inicializar los componentes en tu segundo constructor.

Comment: esta class viajes que nos muestras es el form que debe recibir el dato desde el otro form ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no, es una clase que cree exclusivamente para las consultas al SQL, pero necesito abstraer el dato del form para poder anexarlo a la consulta. hasta el momento el parametro string en el metodo es el más acertado, estoy abstrayendo el texto de form1 a form2, y de ahi agregarlo al string, pero ahora me sale una exception y tengo idea del porque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pasar el dato de un form a otro debes usar el constructor
, entondes desde el form hijo defines

```
public class FormHijo : Form {

   private readonly _datoLabel;

   public FormHijo(string datoLabel){
      _datoLabel = datoLabel;
   }

   public void FormHijo_Load(...)
   {
      viajes v = new viajes();
      var dt = v.MostrarViajes(_datoLabel);

      DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   }
}
```

Tienes que definir el parametro en `MostrarViajes()`

Despues desde el form padre invocas el form hijo usando

```
public class FormPadre : Form {

    public void button1_Click(...)
    {
        FormHijo f = new FormHijo(Label1.Text);
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu aportación,  me servirá más adelante cuando pase los datos de hijo a padre, aunque el problema que tengo aun sigue siendo pasar el dato de padre a hijo.

Comment: Creo que entendiste mal el ejemplo del codigo, este resuelve pasar los datos del form padre al hijo

Comment: cierto, lo andaba probando y quedo perfectamente. Tambien este constructor me va a funcionar para pasar un dato de hijo a padre.Creo tu aporte ha sido más preciso para entender los constructores y sus usos.

Comment: no, para pasar datos del hijo al padre se aplican otra tecnica, pero no se usa el constructor, porque se supone la instancia del forma padre ya existe, no la debes crear nuevamente con el new